# WPF RoutedEvent inconsistency: ListViewItem.MouseDoubleClick Not bubbling correct e.Source

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, binding, routed-events

Binding a RoutedEvent for the "Click" event of static buttons contained in a StackPanel is easy. The RoutedEventArgs will contain the button as the **e.Source** of the event.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Button.Click="RoutedEventHandler">
    <Button Name="btn1" Content="btn1" />
    <Button Name="btn2" Content="btn2" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((FrameworkElement)e.Source).Name);
}
```

However - handling routed events with "ListViewItem.MouseDoubleClick" will result the ListView container object in the **e.Source**, instead of the expected ListViewItem object.

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lbAnecdotes" 
    ListViewItem.MouseDoubleClick="RoutedEventHandler">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView >
```

Can you explain the inconsistency?

Comment: Don't you find it logical that when you set the handler on the `ListView`, you get the same `ListView` as your `e.Source`? You can always refer to `e.OriginalSource` if you want the original source.

Comment: No, please note that this is a **bubbling** event: **ListViewItem**.MouseDoubleClick=...

Comment: Ah. I didn't catch the whole point of your question until I reread it just now. My apologies. And interesting question. +1'd

Comment: What do you expect will see in the `e.Source`? `TextBlock`, `WrapPanel`?

Comment: Equivalently to expecting to see the Button object on the first case (Button.Click), I expect to see the ListViewItem object (ListViewItem.MouseDoubleClick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the `ListViewItem.MouseDoubleClick` event is not a `RoutedEvent` like the `ButtonBase.Click` event. It uses the `MouseButtonEventHandler` delegate and a `Direct` routing strategy where as the `ButtonBase.Click` event is a `RoutedEvent` with a `Bubbling` strategy. They are different types of events and are implemented differently.